# in intelliJ Source Root vs Test Source Root

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, deployment, build, sbt

If i mark `src/main/sourceApp` files as Sources Root  does that make a difference upon how my app is compiled and built and deployed? If so which file setting does this affect.
I currently have  `src/main/sourceApp` as Test Sources Root, but when i deploy my code after doing a Jenkins build, it states that sourceApp is undefined.

> cannot access `sourceApp': No such file or directory

my build sbt contains the following:

```
.settings(name := "csv-rest-service",
    packConf += baseDirectory.value / "src" / "sourceApp" -> "sourceApp",
    version := ABC.acquireVersion.value)
```

Perhaps is there a way to rewrite it with a more 'absolute' path to make sure it is picked up in the build, as right now the artifacts do not contain this folder..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i mark src/main/sourceApp files as Sources Root does that make a
>   difference upon how my app is compiled and built and deployed?

I don't think so. Intellij settings do not influence the SBT Build process (as far I know).

Here is the setting for changing the Source path:

```
scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src"
```

See here the reference: [SBT](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html)